# Programmatically created controls overwriting each other

Tags: asp.net, controls

I'm creating labels in my code behind of C# .net website. The labels hold some standard data which I get back from the server.

The problem I have is I would like to add a button to these created controls (inside the label), but the additional control will overwrite the Text defined in the label.

What are my options to stop this?

```
for (var i = 0; i < (QuoteArray.Length)-1; i++)
        {
            Button[] btnArr = new Button[QuoteArray.Length]; //not used

            var button = new Button
            {
                ID = "Quote_0" + i,
                CommandArgument = "i",
                Text = "!!",
                CssClass = "CountButton"
            };

            Label addL1 = new Label
            {
                ID = "new_labeieeu" + i,
                Text = string.Format("Tariff: {1}</br>Reference: {0}</br>Price: £{3}</br>excl. VAT.</br>Max Passenger: {4}</br>Max Luggage: {5}</br>{2}</br>", QuoteArray[i][0], QuoteArray[i][1], QuoteArray[i][2], QuoteArray[i][3], QuoteArray[i][4], QuoteArray[i][5], QuoteArray[i][6]),
                CssClass ="QuoteButton"

            };
            panelQuote.Controls.Add(addL1);
            addL1.Controls.Add(button);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the button to label, you can do it this way

```
panelQuote.Controls.Add(addL1);
panelQuote.Controls.Add(button);
```

This will add the button next to your label.

Comment: That doesn't work as I want it to, as by design the button should be inside the label

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but I ended up adding another panel, so that both the label and Button when into this one panel, and then I could style them as needed. It does mean 40 odd panels inside one, but that's okay for now.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < (QuoteArray.Length)-1; i++)
        {
            Button[] btnArr = new Button[QuoteArray.Length];

            Panel panel_Inside_Quote = new Panel
            {
                ID = "InnerQuote_" +i,
                CssClass = "QuoteButton"
                //string bob = Convert.ToString(stop);
            };

            panelQuote.Controls.Add(panel_Inside_Quote);

            Button button = new Button
            {
                ID = "Quote_0" + i,
                CommandArgument = "i",
                Text = "!!",
                CssClass = "CountButton"
            };

            Label addL1 = new Label
            {
                ID = "new_labeieeu" + i,
                Text = string.Format("Tariff: {1}</br>Reference: {0}</br>Price: £{3}</br>excl. VAT.</br>Max Passenger: {4}</br>Max Luggage: {5}</br>{2}</br>", QuoteArray[i][0], QuoteArray[i][1], QuoteArray[i][2], QuoteArray[i][3], QuoteArray[i][4], QuoteArray[i][5], QuoteArray[i][6]),
                CssClass ="QuoteButton"

            };
            panel_Inside_Quote.Controls.Add(addL1);
            panel_Inside_Quote.Controls.Add(button);
            //Make_Booking_Page(this, new EventArgs());*/
        }
```

Comment: The other way could be having a label L, then adding the required label and button to this label L. But it still would require programatically finding the point of the required label and then setting the X co-ordinate to +n and then adding the button on that point. But your solution is less clumsy.